# Add a module dependency in Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have got two Maven projects. One of them has to be dependent on the other. I use IntelliJ and I have tried to right click on project1 > Open Module Settings, and in the dependencies tab I clicked on the + symbol to add a directory or jar dependency. So far so good, when I try to import packages from the dependency it autocompletes it for me, however the compilation throws errors, saying that there are no such packages. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why don't you add a dependency in your pom? That's how you add a dependency in a Maven project.

Comment: @JBNizet I started to use Maven yesterday, so I am quite new to this. Can you give me an example how to reference another project ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no notion of project in Maven.

You have a Maven project B. You chose its groupId (com.mycompany, for example), its artifactId (B, for example), and its version (1.0-SNAPSHOT, for example). You run `mvn install` on this project. This generates a B-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file and stores it in your local Maven repository, with its pom.

Now you want to use B-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in another Maven project A. For A, B is a library, just like any other library you use (log4J, Spring, Hibernate, Guava, whatever). So you add a dependency to it in the pom of A, just like you do for any other library:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other dependencies: log4J, Spring, Hibernate, Guava, whatever -->
</dependencies>
```

Read [the awful documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for more details.

Comment: Do I add the dependency into the pom of B or A ?

Comment: In the pom of A, since B is a dependency of A. I fixed the typo in my answer.

Comment: Also, one of the joys of using IntelliJ is how easy it makes for you to add B as a dependency in A's pom. In A's pom, do an 'Alt + Insert', choose 'Dependency Template'. IntelliJ insert a complete dependency tag for you and positions the cursor in the artifactId. All you need to do now is type in the artifcatId of B and the rest will be filled in by IntelliJ. Awesome I'd say !!